# Is the number of ordered and unordered bases of a vector space is same?

Tags: linear-algebra

(1) Is the number of ordered and unordered bases of a vector space is same?

(2) Upto independent is same or not ?

**My approach:**

(1)

Let $B=\{v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n \}$  be an ordered basis.

Then the number of unordered basis is $n!$.

So they are not same.

Am I right?

(2)

Upto independent there is unique basis of a vector space.

In this case number of ordered and unordered basis is same.

Comment: What does "up to independent" mean?

Comment: @ancientmathematician, upto Independent means that a vector space has unique independent basis

Comment: I have no idea what an independent basis is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to (1):

If the field is finite, and the dimension is finite, you are right.

If the field is infinite,and the dimension is finite then the number of bases and the number of unordered bases coincide with the size of the field.

As to (2):

I have no idea what "up to independent" means. But I know of no sense $\mathcal{P}$ in which a vector space of dimension at least $2$ has a unique basis up to $\mathcal{P}$. It seems to me that whatever you mean $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and $\{(1,1),(-1,1)\}$ are independent bases of $\mathbb{R}^2$.