# Basis (linear algebra) - ordering of the vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, article-writing

Looking at Wikipedia [Basis (linear algebra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)), it seems that in English a basis is a set of vectors that may be ordered, with ordering not being mandatory. This creates issues when dealing with coordinates of vectors.

In French a **"base"** is supposed to be ordered.

**Do we have to mention an *ordered basi*s to stipulate explicitly in English that the basis is ordered? Or does in practice a basis have implicitly an order?**

*Note: this question has [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3327651/is-the-number-of-ordered-and-unordered-bases-of-a-vector-space-is-same) for background.*

Comment: Do you mean there is an ordering relation (ref, trans, antisymm) imposed on the basis?

Comment: @AlvinLepik Thanks for the comment. I know that the order matters for coordinates. The issue is that Wikipedia doesn't state an order to be mandatory. The paragraph [Coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Coordinates) details the topic of ordered basis.

Comment: @AlvinLepik Yes, I mean having an ordering imposed on the basis.

Comment: In my mind, a basis does not automatically come with an order (and indeed the order is usually superfluous). There are times when the order of the basis matters (Gram–Schmidt, for example), and in that case I'm used to either seeing the words "ordered basis" explicitly, or else the author sloppily assuming that the reader can figure out that an order is needed.

Comment: @GregMartin Right, but when one reads about the Gram-Schmidt process, the ordering is implicit in the algorithm, no?

Comment: "implicit in the algorithm" and "the reader can figure out that an order is needed" are two ways of saying the same thing :)

Comment: @GregMartin Right, note to self - read all of the comment before replying

Comment: @GregMartin If you have time to turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it. It gives me some hints on the way to read English math!

Comment: It's recommended to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer—it gives users an incentive to keep trying to supply you with good information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my mind, a basis does not automatically come with an order (and indeed the order is usually superfluous). There are times when the order of the basis matters (Gram–Schmidt, for example), and in that case I'm used to either seeing the words "ordered basis" explicitly, or else the author sloppily assuming that the reader can figure out that an order is needed.